# What is the AutoIt script to select an option from the drop down list?

Tags: drop-down-menu, autoit

I am not able to select an option from a drop down list while testing an application using AutoIt.

Though I am able to send the option using `Send("{down}{down}")`, it will be difficult to select the option when a large number of elements are present in the list. And the problem is that the `Send({down}{down})` command is sending the text, not selecting the text.

The option must be get selected by the cursor, not just get sent, and it should be easy to select any option, irrespective of how many there are or what their order is.

Answer (score 1):

hi kiran myself i am a learner too but i used control send "unique starting letters for the option (only if unable to find its direct control id){ENTER}" to control id for selcting option from a long list directly ok this is my fist forum even i dont know to use return in forums posting so please dont mind my indentation and decoration for this answer and please let me know if you find difficulty hope this helps

Comment: Hi again found you can use controlcommand. "SelectString", 'string' Sets selection according to string in a ListBox or ComboBox hope that helps ashish

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine.. You can use this..

```
ControlCommand("Age Calculator", "", "[CLASS:ThunderRT6ComboBox; INSTANCE:2]","SelectString","November")
```